# Confirm Java Copy By Value

Tags: java

Question on variable placement and confirming a copy is performed.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void question() {
    int c[] = new int[]{0};
    /*Questions:
     * 1.) Is j in the stack?
     * 2.) When assigning j, is a copy of the value c[0] performed?*/
    int j = c[0];
}
```

Comment: I think ```j``` is a copy. The way to test it is to modify ```c[0]``` and see if the value of ```j``` changes

Comment: I did not think about how to test it like you recommended. I tried it and a copy is performed as you suggested.

Comment: The term for what @jpuriol is talking about is "aliasing", when two references point to the same object and that object is modified (instead of replaced by changing a reference to point to a different object). Problems related to aliasing are one of the main motivations for using *immutable objects* (and all of the primitive wrappers such as `Integer` are immutable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java only ever copies values. Sometimes those values are references to objects, but here the value is an `int` primitive. The value for `j` is on the stack because it's a local variable (as is the value for `c`, which is a reference to an array that is itself located on the heap but will soon be garbage-collected).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. To save a reference to a primitive is not possible in Java?

Comment: @RodrigoGomez References are "pointers" (more or less) to objects. Both references and primitives are immediate values, and you can't have a reference to a primitive. Depending on your goal, you can have a reference to an array of primitives (the array is an object), or use a wrapper class such as `Integer` or `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the result of of `c[0]` is copied into the `j` variable, because int is a primitive type, and is copied by value. If you were to use the `Integer` class, the reference would be copied and not the value itself.

Comment: No, Java *always* copies values. If the OP used the `Integer` class, the value of the array element would be a reference, and that value would be copied. But it would still be copied - there'd be no lasting association between `j` and `c[0]`... if you changed the value of `c[0]` to a different reference, that wouldn't change `j`.

Comment: That's a bit better, but it suggests that the value of the array element would be the `Integer` object - it wouldn't be. The values of variables, including array elements, are *never* objects - *only* ever references or primitive type values. The statement `j = c[0];` always copies the value of the array element `c[0]`, whether that's a reference or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet I love feeling enlightened when I'm answering a question, thank you Daisy Shipton :)

Answer (score 1):

Java is always pass by value. What it means is when X = Y then X gets the value of Y. If it's the case of primitives like int then value is copied as primitives are available as values directly. If it's the case of objects then references to objects are copied as objects are available via references only.